# how to insert into table with preselected values from a minus query?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I get specific values by using a statement like

```
select id from x minus (select id from y)
```

it returns multiple rows which I all need to insert into another table. How do I achieve this?

I tried something like this which didnt work:

```
insert into table (id, name) values((select id from x minus (select id from y), 'name')
```

so the table in the end has all values I got before plus another column with 'name' in it.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: By the way, the set operators don't require any special brackets, so it's just `select xx from x minus select yy from y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use :

```
insert into yourFinalTable(id, name)
select id, 'name' from x minus select id, 'name' from y;
```

Comment: The insert should have two columns.

Comment: select id, name ... name does not exist as column name.

Comment: @M4V3N is it enough to insert the column ID then, or what else I should consider for replacing with the column name in table x ..?

Comment: if this statement "select id from x minus (select id from y)" returns 1,2,3,4 as ids. I want to insert them into another table and they end up being like [1,name][2,name][3,name][4,name] so 4 rows but 2 columns. Column 1 has to be the ids and column 2 is simply 'name'

Comment: @M4V3N do you mean a constant literal with 'name' or a variable column values such as John, Adams, ... ?

Comment: a string constant only

Comment: @M4V3N then so simple, I edited. We just need to convert to a literal as 'name'.

Comment: alright thanks, I can test it in some hours and will let you know if it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

tihs will work:

```
create table ns_table3(val1 varchar(20));
create table ns_table4(val2 varchar(20));
insert into ns_table3 values('1');
insert into ns_table3 values('2');
insert into ns_table3 values('3');
insert into ns_table3 values('4');
insert into ns_table4 values('1');
insert into ns_table4 values('2');
select * from ns_table3;
1
2
3 
4
select * from ns_table4;
1
2
create table ns_table5(val1 varchar(20),val2 varchar(20));


insert into ns_table5  select val1,'name' from ns_table3 minus select val2,'name' from ns_table4;
select * from ns_table5;
sample ouput required:
3   name
4   name
```